# will iPhone 14 have the physical SIM slot in europe?

Tags: iphone, sim, esim

I live in Italy and i want to buy an iPhone 14 Pro when it comes out, but I don`t know if for the European iPhone models there will be the physical SIM slot as they announced that in the US the iPhone 14 will only have e-SIM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhones 14 for Europe / Italy use physical nano-SIM and [eSIM](https://support.apple.com/en-bw/HT209096).  Only phones sold through US channels are eSIM only, so [Asia, Europe, Africa, Canada and Mexico, Latin and Central and South America](https://www.apple.com/choose-country-region/) all still have a physical nano-SIM as well as an eSIM.

> Dual SIM (nano‑SIM + eSIM)

https://support.apple.com/it-it/HT212780